# Asp.net count user attempt

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to ASP.net It might be a simple question but I  dont know how to do it.
I have a asp.wizard control on my page where On "step 1" I have one textbox that accept a order number
If user enter the order number  in textbox and it match with the database it move user to wizard step 2. If user  entered wrong value or  kept it blank then  validator controls warn to enter value or entered value is wrong.
However my concern it that if user try to input value more then **three time** it should show the popup window and say the message "you have tried three times and you dont have a valid order number" 
I tried to  increment my counter in  serverValidate event function but its reseting the counter value to 0 on every postback of the page.
I dont now how to do it as  everytime my page postback after clicking next button o my wizard page my counter value reset to 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (Wizard1.ActiveStepIndex == 0)
    {
        if ((HiddenField1.Value == "0")){
            HiddenField1.Value = "1";
    }
        else if ((HiddenField1.Value == "1"))
      {
          HiddenField1.Value = "2";
      }

      else if ((HiddenField1.Value == "2"))
      {
          HiddenField1.Value = "3";

          Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('you tried 3 times')</script>");
          }



    Label21.Text = HiddenField1.Value;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can save it in a session variable that one would not reset.

Comment: please provide the code where should I use session on page_load or where and how. I am really new to asp.net.

Comment: how to do in session.  I tried to save in session in my page_load event but its say session is right in current context ViewState("MyCounter")

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdn" runat="server" value="0" />
```

On code behind, after each failed attempt:

```
hdn.Value=""+(ConvertToInt32(hdn.Value)+1);
if(hdn.Value=="3")
// do something
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply, but where I am putting this code in my code behind file. on page_load event or where

Comment: @uture: the markup (`<input type="hidden" ...`) anywhere inside your form. The code behind, right when you do the validation against the database to make sure the order number entered was accurate.

Comment: giving error on 

hdn.Value=""+int.Parse(hdn.Value)+1; Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: @future Try:    `hdn.Value=""+(ConvertToInt32(hdn.Value)+1);`

Comment: Error The name 'ConvertToInt32' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0):

Store your counter in a hidden text field. This way the value will survive postbacks. You can either increment the counter in javascript (when the user presses the button) or on the server.

Here is a rough framework:

Add a field to your page similar to the following:

```
    <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="txtCounter" />
```

In your code-behind:

```
if String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCounter.Value) {
   txtCounter.Value = "1";
} else {
   int wCounter;
   wCounter = Convert.ToInt32(txtCounter.Value);
   if (wCounter >= 3) {
     Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "Count Exceeded", "alert('The number of tries has been exceeded.');", True)

   } else {
     wCounter += 1;
     txtCounter.Value = wCounter.ToString();
   }
}
```

Comment: could you  give any example code how to do that. I am hitting my head to do this for hours

Comment: Google it, and you will have multiple samples on your hand

Comment: where should I put that code behind code. on page_load event or where

Comment: I used that code in my  next_button click event and its does give any popup after third attempt

Comment: it doesnt give any popup sorry for above comment I meant doesnt give nay popup